# All my Likes are deleted ? Wrong LIKE-url in my script?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I used for my website the following LIKE BUTTON (script)

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2Fsearchjobsabroad%2F132117540199153&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=220&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:220px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true">

</iframe>
```

This worked for months..........and I had over 200 LIKES.

Since 2 weeks my button dissepaered.

I think there is something wrong with the like url I used ?

http://www.facebook.com/pages/searchjobsabroad/132117540199153 (this one I used)

Well what should I do now ? I already created a new button,.......and I tried if it works. It works with the new like button script but all my LIKES are lost !!!!

What should I do now to get all my likes back ? I cannot find them anymore / they are not displayed anymore :-(

Comment: This is against the Facebook TOS. You're tricking users into liking things just by visiting your page. People probably reported you to Facebook. Had you done the same to me, I'd have reported you too.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Facebook either deleted your page or you unpublished it, stopping the Like button from working. You can try contacting Facebook to see what happened, you should have gotten an email from Facebook to indicate it is deleting the page for violating the Terms of Service.

Facebook will undelete the page if you prove that you didn't violate the TOS or tricked users into Liking the page. Otherwise, all your Likes are lost forever.